# PZL-104 Wilga and Wilga 2000 slats question

Tags: aircraft-design, aerodynamics, slats

Looking at some details about this aircraft's wing, I wondered why the latest version slat's design
has been modified so that it is no longer a continuous slat that runs the whole wingspan, rather there are now two separate elements that stop at fuselage or wing roots.

What is behind this design modification and why has the "full span" slat from the older version been removed for the newest design?

Here's a picture of the continuous slat on older version.

[image: continuous slat]
([source](http://flightplanet.com/aircraftimg/28939/585x0/pzl-104-wilga-35__1.jpg))

Here's a pictrure of the discontinued slat on Wilga 2000

[image: discontinued slat]
([source](https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.airwar.ru%2Fimage%2Fidop%2Fla%2Fpzl104m%2Fpzl104m-1.jpg&f=1&nofb=1&ipt=c55f2eb31fd6e834b738df4bb0bf4b4ace9a87584d133f69e62ef36320734165&ipo=images))